# Mac equivalent bless on Linux

Tags: linux, macos

Is there any equivalent mac "bless" command in Linux. I am specifically interested in the option "--bless-folder".

Answer (score 1):

No. You'll need to configure things like `grub` to specify where it should find your kernel, and what arguments to pass to the kernel. Quite often the arguments to the kernel would include:

- `root=/dev/sda1` which means the filesystem can be found on a particular partition of a particular disk;
- `init=/sbin/init` which is the very first file the kernel executes, which loads the whole of the rest of the OS.

Comment: I have an option with "genisoimage" which has "--hfs-bless". But this doesn't solve my problem as i need to open a specific folder in the generated image. Is it a wise decision to compile the "bless" source on native linux?.

Comment: Hmm. Are you trying to (1) configure Linux to load its kernel and system files from a certain location (in which case see my previous answer); or (2) create a disk image on Linux but to boot a Mac; or (3)  something else? If you literally want to "open" a folder under Linux then I'd consider creating a shell script which runs `xdg-open` or `gnome-open` (though I'm not sure how/whether you can configure a script to run when a CD is inserted). That's different from the function of `bless` I think, which is specifically to mark folders as bootable. Can you explain more what you want?

Comment: I am trying to create an ISO image with "genisoimage -r -J -V "top -o top.iso top" where in I have a folder structure as "top/sub". I would like to open the folder "sub" as soon as i insert the top.iso image in MAC. I can do this is in MAC but finally i need to generate this image on arm linux. So, I am looking for a way to bless the folder with "-open-folder" option in Linux

Comment: Ah OK, I hadn't seen the `-openfolder` suboption. Sorry, I don't know.